# Building and deploying multi platform nw.js apps from a mac

Tags: nw.js

A bit of advice appreciated here before I start this. Hopefully the question will help other newbie users of nw.js as well.

I develop on a mac and I have build and deployed an HTML5 app using nw.js that runs successfully on a mac.

My question is simple. Can I build for windows and linux whilst still working from my mac, or do I need to invest in a windows machine and build it from there. Ditto for Linux.

My reason for asking is also because I read somewhere that the node modules installed in the package are not the same for each platform. I suppose you could say I have just answered my own question, but here's hoping!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes you can. I did (at least I have build for both Mac and Windows from Mac, I have not attempted Linux yet).
The mac build was easy. The windows build requires that you install wine (brew install wine, hopefully you installed node with brew, so brew is already on your system. If you did not, I recommend first removing node (very carefully!) and reinstalling it with brew).
Wine is required by the node build programmes (I use nw-builder-phoenix) to create the windows installer.
Wine has a few pre-requisites as well  (cask, java and xquartz).
But having done all of this and re-run the build programme, it all works.
The icon format is different, .ico for windows apps and .icns for mac. They can both be generated from a .png file either using an app or a website.
Have fun.